# Long text is showing as Chinese characters in query on MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following query that an Access report is based on. On two different fields, which are "long texts" in the query, it shows up as symbols.

```
SELECT qryCA.CASSIRecordNum, 
Replace(qryCA.[TypeInspection],"_"," ") AS TypeInspection, 
qryCA.SSI_Record_Name, 
qryCA.Phonenumber, 
qryCA.InspectedBY, 
qryCA.Project, 
qryCA.DateTimeInspection, 
qryCA.Question, 
qryCA.Describe, 
qryCA.DispatchStatus, 
qryCA.ProjectSupervisor, 
qryCA.Date_Time_Form_Opened, 
qryCA.Date_Time_Form_Submitted, 
qryCA.Was_the_corrective_action_comp, 
qryCA.Why, 
qryCA.Corrective_Action_Completed_By, 
qryCA.Date_Time_Corrective_Action_Co, Left(qryCA.Rank,1) AS Rank
FROM qryCA

WHERE (((qryCA.SSI_Record_Name) Is Not Null));
```

The two fields that are showing up as Chinese characters are  qryCA.Describe,   and    qryCA.Why.

I have been searching for a solution and tried a compact and repair as that was suggested. I also saw a suggestion that this bug can be due to grouping on a memo/long text field. But there is no grouping in my query. The table, qryCA does not show any Chinese characters.

Comment: Where are they showing up with the wrong charset?  It's not clear why you have this tagged with VBA.

Comment: They are showing up within the query itself as well as the report the query is based on. I removed the VBA tag, that was done mistakenly.

Comment: How does qryCA display?

Comment: qryCA displays in the correct text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
Left(qryCA.Describe, 255),
```

or:

```
Mid(qryCA.Describe, 1),
```

though these will truncate a long text.
Eventually (from qryCA or - better - its source table):

```
DLookup("[Describe]", "qryCA", "[CASSIRecordNum]=" & CASSIRecordNum & "") As FullDescribe,
```

This will, however, be quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there are records in your table with corrupted data. Open the table directly and sort on the fields qryCA.Describe and qryCA.Why. Either sort A-Z or Z-A and see if the faulty records show up on top. The records with errors in them will have these characters as well. These should probably be deleted, re-enter the data a new records if you have to. These are errors that a compact/repair can't always fix by itself.